# Same formula but different result in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, statistics, landsat-7, normalized-difference-water-index

Earlier, I asked [Calculating statistical values from set of point values in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/462844/115) regarding extraction of MNDWI values using sample points, which got resolved. But in that code, I am finding some discrepancies, and hence, I am confused which one is actually correct, and can be used for further analyses. I am providing the code below:

```
var IHR = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/nmsheiari223/assets/Uttarakhand');

// LOADING LANDSAT COLLECTION
//cloud mask
function maskL8sr(col) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = col.select('QA_PIXEL');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return col.updateMask(mask);
}

//DERIVING THE SPECTRAL INDICES (OPTIONAL: TO INCREASE THE ACCURACY)
function addmndwiL(input) {
  var mndwiL = input.normalizedDifference(['SR_B2', 'SR_B5']).rename('mndwiL');
  return input.addBands(mndwiL);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')
    .filterDate('2000-10-01', '2000-11-30')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',30)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(IHR)})
    .map(maskL8sr)
    .map(addmndwiL)
    ;
    

// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
}

dataset = dataset.map(applyScaleFactors);

var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
};

Map.centerObject(IHR, 8);

var collectionL = dataset.median();
Map.addLayer(collectionL, visualization, 'RGBL (432)');

//Extracting values
var sampled_points = collectionL.select('mndwiL').sampleRegions({ 
  collection: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  geometries: true
});

var stats = sampled_points.aggregate_stats('mndwiL');
print ('statistical values', stats);

var min = sampled_points.aggregate_min('SR_B2');
print ('min', min);

print('List items less than 0',
      sampled_points.filter(ee.Filter.lt('mndwiL',0)));
var samples = sampled_points.filter(ee.Filter.gte('mndwiL',0));
var stats1 = samples.aggregate_stats('mndwiL');
print ('new statistical values', stats1);
var mean = samples.aggregate_mean('mndwiL');
print('Sample Mean', mean);
var std = samples.aggregate_sample_sd('mndwiL');
print('Sample Standard Deviation', std);

//Calculating the upper and lower threshold values
var Uth = mean.add(std.multiply(3));
var Lth =  mean.subtract(std.multiply(3));
print('Upper Threshold', Uth, 'Lower Threshold', Lth);
```

When I am using the above code, the statistical values and the estimated thresholds are coming as shown in the below picture.

[image]

But if I use the below code for calculating the MNDWI (manually), I am getting different result!

```
var green = collectionL.select('SR_B2');
var swir = collectionL.select('SR_B5');

var N = green.subtract(swir);
var D = green.add(swir);
var MNDWI = N.divide(D);
Map.addLayer(MNDWI, {}, 'MNDWI');

//Extracting values
var sampled_points = MNDWI.sampleRegions({ 
  collection: geometry,
  scale: 30,
  geometries: true
});

var stats = sampled_points.aggregate_stats('SR_B2');
print ('statistical values', stats);

var min = sampled_points.aggregate_min('SR_B2');
print ('min', min);

print('List items less than 0',
      sampled_points.filter(ee.Filter.lt('SR_B2',0)));
var samples = sampled_points.filter(ee.Filter.gte('SR_B2',0));
var stats1 = samples.aggregate_stats('SR_B2');
print ('new statistical values', stats1);
var mean = samples.aggregate_mean('SR_B2');
print('Sample Mean', mean);
var std = samples.aggregate_sample_sd('SR_B2');
print('Sample Standard Deviation', std);

//Calculating the upper and lower threshold values
var Uth = mean.add(std.multiply(3));
var Lth =  mean.subtract(std.multiply(3));
print('Upper Threshold', Uth, 'Lower Threshold', Lth);
```

The result in this case is coming as below picture.

[image]

In both the cases I'm using the MNDWI formula as:

[image]

The same bands are used in the two methods. Also, the samples are same for estimating the statistical values. Where am I going wrong? Why I am getting two different sets of estimated values using the same formula?

Note: In the second method, while calculating the stats, the property name is chosen as 'SR_B2' because, I tried exporting the extracted values in csv format, and there only the column heading was mentioned as 'SR_B2' (though I don't exactly understand why it is taking so). But I guess it contains the calculated MNDWI (2nd method tried here) only, because, it contains two negative values for two samples (which might be correct, as MNDWI ranges from -1 to +1). If it was the actual surface reflectance values from Band 2, I guess it won't have the negative values then, as the surface reflectance ranges from 0 to 1. Am I guessing correct here?

Comment: Are you performing the same cloud-masking and scaling operations in the second example? If so, please be sure to include them in the code.

Comment: In the first example, I am creating an image collection named "dataset" which actually includes the cloud masking and the scaling using the mentioned factors. There only, before calling the image collection, the function for MNDWI is created and added as a band in the dataset. It is giving the 1st set of result. I the 2nd example, however, I'm creating "collectionL" by taking the median of "dataset". And to generate the MNDWI manually, the bands are selected from "collectionL" only. As it is the median of the "dataset", I guess, it includes the cloud masking and the scaling also.